# Hosting Gatsby Blog within Express Application

Tags: javascript, gatsby

This may be a stupid question and if so apologies. I have my website hosted on Heroku (Express application). I also have a blog I have created with Gatsby, I want to host Gatsby @ www.mysite.com/blog, can I host my Gatsby app from within my Express app and if so how do I call Gatsby from my Express routes.

Thanks

Comment: Have you followed the "getting started" for Express? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have actually now found a solution to my issue, could you please link me to the aforementioned "getting started for Express", more specifically the part the explains this as I was unable to find such documentation.

Comment: [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this is actually pretty simple, because Gatsby just generates static HTML, CSS and JS. These files can be served at a specific route from App.js in my case "/blog".

The key is to make sure that you have path prefix set up in Gatsby before you build your application and deploy the files. This means when the application is build all assets are prefixed with "/blog" meaning the assets can be found within a subfolder inside an Express application.

**App.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/blog', express.static(__dirname + '/blog/public'));
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/communicate', sendMail);
```

**Gatsy-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: '/blog',
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: urljoin(config.siteUrl),
    rssMetadata: {
      site_url: urljoin(config.siteUrl),
      feed_url: urljoin(config.siteUrl, config.pathPrefix, config.siteRss),
      title: config.siteTitle,
      description: config.siteDescription,
      image_url: `${urljoin(
        config.siteUrl,
        config.pathPrefix
      )}/logos/logo-512.png`,
      copyright: config.copyright
    }
```